# how to call a function inside the map by using markers properties

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic3

I tried to load some location on a marker and it is properly loading. now I want to call a function when I click the marker. I implemented the function as follow.

```
loadMap(clat, clon) {
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clon);

let mapOptions = {
  center: latLng,
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, mapOptions);
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clon),
  map: this.map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 7,
    strokeColor: '#0057ff'
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, I;

this.sellers.forEach(element => {
  console.log("where am i:" + element.location.la)

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(element.location.la, element.location.lo),
    map: this.map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
      infowindow.setContent(element.name + '<button ion-button (click)="{{test}}">Vist Shop</button>');
      infowindow.open(this.map, marker);

      this.type = element.sellertype;
      this.selectShopType(this.type)


    }
  })(marker, i));

});


}
```

In this function, I'm calling "selectShopType()" function but I'm receiving an error called

> selectShopType() is not a function

. How can I call the outer function by using marker properties

Comment: I don't see any function  selectShopType()   ..you are just invoking  a function that  not exist  .. be sure of what is `this` in the context you are calling   `this.selectShopType(this.type)` and be sure this have  the function you need

Comment: I wrote that selectShopType() function at the inside of the loadMAp() method. but it didn't work. after that i replace that function outside the loadMAap() method. still it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You  have not a function selectShopType function and so you should add this function a top level  scope

```
function  selectShopType(myvalue){

    alert('My value is : ' + myvalue);
    return;
}

loadMap(clat, clon) {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clon);

    let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clon),
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 7,
            strokeColor: '#0057ff'
        }
    });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

this.sellers.forEach(element => {
    console.log("where am i:" + element.location.la)

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(element.location.la, element.location.lo),
        map: this.map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(element.name + '<button ion-button (click)="{{test}}">Vist Shop</button>');
        infowindow.open(this.map, marker);

        this.type = element.sellertype;
        selectShopType(this.type);


    }
})(marker, i));

});

}
```

Comment: thanks. but here also same result. occurs error as a "Uncaught TypeError: this.selectShopType is not a function"

Comment: in my code there is not the code   `this.selectShopType `..,but `selectShopType(this.type);`  .. so check better for my code

Comment: i also use your code segment that you have mention above, but it is not working for me because when i using selectShopType(this.type); as you mention i'm getting an error called [ts] Cannot find name 'selectShopType'. That's why i using "this.selectShopType"

Comment: My problem is, i want call function in this page but out side the load map function. but its not working by the reason that marker click event. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below function which I used

```
this.map.addMarker(options).then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
         marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
        .subscribe(e => {
          console.log(“you clicked me");
          //implement the function 
               });
          });
```

Comment: It's really helpfull